# Skipping over Scanf statement in C

Tags: c

I am writing an objective c program for hangman. I need to replicate another program which has been given to me. I have done most of it, but am having an issue. It has to replicate the other program exactly, so I went into the other one and entered a character into the wordlength. It came up with the "number must be between 3 and 14 (inclusive)" statement, and asked me to enter a number again, but it started to loop infinitely. It works when i enter a number lower than 3 and larger than 14 (comes up with the error and asks for another input) but with a letter it infinitely loops. Any ideas???
Thanks

```
while (i == 0){

            printf("\n\n > Please enter a word length: ");
                scanf("%i", &wordLength);
            printf("\n\n");
            if (number > 3 && number < 14) {
                continue;
            }
            else printf("number must be between 3 and 14 (inclusive)");
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking `number` but seems that you must check `wordLength` variable, and (as pointed out by @Narkha) use `break` instead of `continue` to exit from loop.

Answer (score 1):

`while (i == 0)` will loop as long as `i` stays at value `0`. I don't see `i` being modified anywhere in your code, so there's probably a bug.

Edit: Alter Mann's answer is even better.

Answer (score 0):

The loop continue because you are never altering `i` and `i = 0` is altways true; `continue` make that the code jump to the loop condicion, no end the loop. Also, as @AlterMann comments, you are not checking wordLength, i suggest this

```
    bool continueLoop = true;
    while (continueLoop ){
        printf("\n\n > Please enter a word length: ");
        scanf("%i", &wordLength);
        printf("\n\n");

        if (wordLength > 3 && wordLength < 14) {
            continueLoop  = false;
        }
        else {
            printf("number must be between 3 and 14 (inclusive)");
        }
    }
```

Or maybe use `break` and end the loop without flags

```
    while (true){
        printf("\n\n > Please enter a word length: ");
        scanf("%i", &wordLength);
        printf("\n\n");

        if (wordLength > 3 && wordLength < 14) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("number must be between 3 and 14 (inclusive)");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getchar() after scanf() for avoid newline character left in stdin.

```
while (i == 0){

            printf("\n\n > Please enter a word length: ");
                scanf("%d", &wordLength);
                getchar();
            printf("\n\n");
            if (number > 3 && number < 14) {
                break;
            }
            else printf("number must be between 3 and 14 (inclusive)");
            }
```